# Convert flat array to tree structure

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a flat array that I'm getting from a MySQL query but I need to convert it into a tree structure. I've been trying to do this for a while now but can't seem to get it done.

It's basically for navigation in a web app. Some nodes will have children but others will not.

I've tried using ES6 array functions like reduce, map, etc but I can't get the child elements to show up.

Here's the structure...

```
[
  {
    "page_id": 1,
    "page_name": "dashboard",
    "path": "/",
    "page_icon": "dashboard",
    "sub_page_id": 0,
    "sub_page_name": null,
    "sub_page_path": null,
    "sub_page_icon": null,
    "parent_id": 0
  },
  {
    "page_id": 2,
    "page_name": "Transactions",
    "path": "/transactions",
    "page_icon": "swap_horiz",
    "sub_page_id": 0,
    "sub_page_name": null,
    "sub_page_path": null,
    "sub_page_icon": null,
    "parent_id": 0
  },
  {
    "page_id": 6,
    "page_name": "Reports",
    "path": null,
    "page_icon": null,
    "sub_page_id": 1,
    "sub_page_name": "Transactions Value",
    "sub_page_path": "/transactions-value",
    "sub_page_icon": "assessment",
    "parent_id": 6
  },
  {
    "page_id": 6,
    "page_name": "Reports",
    "path": null,
    "page_icon": null,
    "sub_page_id": 2,
    "sub_page_name": "Transactions Volume",
    "sub_page_path": "/transactions-volume",
    "sub_page_icon": "assessment",
    "parent_id": 6
  },
  {
    "page_id": 6,
    "page_name": "Reports",
    "path": null,
    "page_icon": null,
    "sub_page_id": 3,
    "sub_page_name": "Transactions Frequency",
    "sub_page_path": "/transactions-frequency",
    "sub_page_icon": "assessment",
    "parent_id": 6
  },
  {
    "page_id": 8,
    "page_name": "Holidays",
    "path": null,
    "page_icon": null,
    "sub_page_id": 7,
    "sub_page_name": "My Holidays",
    "sub_page_path": "/my-holidays",
    "sub_page_icon": "wb_sunny",
    "parent_id": 8
  },
  {
    "page_id": 8,
    "page_name": "Holidays",
    "path": null,
    "page_icon": null,
    "sub_page_id": 8,
    "sub_page_name": "Add User",
    "sub_page_path": "/add-user",
    "sub_page_icon": "person_add",
    "parent_id": 8
  },
  {
    "page_id": 8,
    "page_name": "Holidays",
    "path": null,
    "page_icon": null,
    "sub_page_id": 9,
    "sub_page_name": "Add Site",
    "sub_page_path": "/add-site",
    "sub_page_icon": "location_on",
    "parent_id": 8
  },
  {
    "page_id": 10,
    "page_name": "Logout",
    "path": "/logout",
    "page_icon": "input",
    "sub_page_id": 0,
    "sub_page_name": null,
    "sub_page_path": null,
    "sub_page_icon": null,
    "parent_id": 0
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: please add the data in literal notation and what you have tried, as well as the result.

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz, I've done that for you. I recall you helping me with a similar issue a while back. I'd be really grateful if you can give me another hand. Not all the data is there as Stackoverflow wouldn't allow it but the basic structure is there.

Comment: why do you have same `page_id` and `parent_id`? please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz, if you look at the table, these are 2 tables joined together (pages & sub_pages table). parent_id is the foreign key that references the pages table so the sub page "Transactions Value" is a sub page of "Reports".

I want Reports, Holidays, Demos and Tools to only appear once and everything in the sub_pages table to be children of those nodes where the parent_id patches page_id.

Comment: ok. but is see not result.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, you could use a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
myArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!curr.sub_page_id)
    acc[curr.page_id] = curr
  else
    acc[curr.page_id].children = acc[curr.page_id].children
      ? acc[curr.page_id].children[curr.sub_page_id] = curr
      : acc[curr.page_id].children = { [sub_page_id]: curr }
  return acc
}, {})
```

Comment: That's not working mate. Getting "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

Comment: Where do you see a `push`?

Also, this wasn't meant as a copy/paste solution. Just something to get you started. This will undoubtedly fail if the parent doesn't exist in the object before you try to append a child prop onto it.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it guys. May not be the most efficient method but it works.

```
const data = response.data;
const tree = [];

data.reduce(function(a, b, i, r) {

    // Add the parent nodes
    if(a.page_id != b.page_id){
        tree.push({ page_id: a.page_id,
                        page_name: a.page_name,
                        page_path: a.path,
                        page_icon: a.page_icon
                    });
    }

    // Add the last parent node
    if(i+1 == data.length) {
        tree.push({ page_id: b.page_id,
                        page_name: b.page_name,
                        page_path: b.path,
                        page_icon: b.page_icon
                    });

        // Add the child nodes to the parent nodes
        data.reduce(function(a, b) {
            if(a.sub_page_id) {
                const find = tree.findIndex(f => f.page_id == a.parent_id);

                // Add the first child node to parent
                if(!("children" in tree[find])) {
                    tree[find].children = [];

                    tree[find].children.push({ page_id: a.sub_page_id,
                                                page_name: a.sub_page_name,
                                                page_path: a.sub_page_path,
                                                page_icon: a.sub_page_icon
                    });
                }
                // Add the remaining child nodes to parent nodes
                else {
                    tree[find].children.push({ page_id: a.sub_page_id,
                                                page_name: a.sub_page_name,
                                                page_path: a.sub_page_path,
                                                page_icon: a.sub_page_icon
                    });
                }
            }
            return b;
        });
    }
    return b;
});
```

Comment: great for you. but a shame, that we could not help, because of the missing result.